# Speeding up simple math operations on numeric 2D array (matrix) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have a numeric 2D array (an array of arrays, or a matrix) and I need to do simple matrix operations like adding a value to each row, or multiplying every value by a single number.  I have little experience with math operations in `JavaScript`, so this may be a bone-headed code snippet.  It is also very slow, and I need to use it when the number of columns is 10,000 - 30,000.  By very slow I mean roughly 500 ms to process a row of 2,000 values.  Bummer.

```
var ran2Darray = function(row, col){
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < row; i++) {
        res[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            res[i][j] = Math.random();
        }
    }
    return res;
}

var myArray = ran2Darray(5, 100);
var offset = 2;

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    aRow = myArray[i];
    st = Date.now();
    aRow.map(function addNumber(offset) {myArray[i] + offset*i; })
    end = Date.now();
    document.write(end - st);
    document.write("</br>");
    myArray[i] = aRow;
}
```

I want to avoid any added libraries or frameworks, unless of course, that is my only option.  Can this code be made faster, or is there another direction I can go, like passing the calculation to another language?  I'm just not familiar with how people deal with this sort of problem. `forEach` performs roughly the same, by the way.

Comment: `Array.map` as well as `forEach` calls a function for each element. Try replacing that with a for loop.

Comment: Right you are!  Thanks, this is the kind of thing I don't yet really appreciate in `JavaScript`.  In my usual language, `R`, these sorts of things are highly optimized and the mapped version is usually faster.  I rewrote it to use 2 indices and for a 5 x 50000 matrix it took 7 ms.  The answer from @Artyom took 47 ms (but I learned several things from that answer).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to rewrite array items several times. `.map()` returns a new array, so just assign it to the current index:

```
var myArray = ran2Darray(5, 100000);
var offset = 2;

var performOperation = function(value, idx) {
    return value += offset * idx;
}

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.time(i);
    myArray[i] = myArray[i].map(performOperation)
    console.timeEnd(i);
}
```

It takes like ~20ms to process.

[Fiddle demo (open console)](http://jsfiddle.net/as4yLppu/)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful and fast, though slightly slower than just using two loops (see comment on original question).  I learned a couple of helpful things from your example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Just a little modification and a bug fix in what you have presented here.

```
function addNumber(offset) {myArray[i] + offset*i; }) is not good.
```

myArray[i] is the first dimention of a 2D array why to add something to it?

```
function ran2Darray (row, col) {

    var res = [];

    for (var i = 0 ; i < row; i++) {

        res[i] = [];

        for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            res[i][j] = Math.random();
        }
    }
    return res;
}

var oneMillion = 1000000;
var myArray = ran2Darray(10, oneMillion);
var offset = 2;
var startTime, endTime;

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

    startTime = Date.now();
    myArray[i] = myArray[i].map(function (offset) {

        return (offset + i) * offset;
    });
    endTime = Date.now();

    document.write(endTime - startTime);
    document.write("</br>");
}
```

try it. It's really fast
https://jsfiddle.net/itaymer/8ttvzyx7/

Comment: Thank you, more good stuff for me to study.  Looks a little slower than @Artyom 's answer.  Much appreciated, I knew I wasn't doing it quite right.